# What happens if validator count < minimum_validator_count?

Tags: consensus, staking, validator, election

I am using the staking pallet and it has an item known as `minimum_validator_count`. I'd like to learn what would happen if the actual validators in the network is less than this entity. Would the election fail to give a usable result? Will no blocks be finalized until the minimum validator count is met?

Also as a bonus question, how is it possible to increase this quantity in a running chain?

**Edit #1**: I've found a few calls in the staking module that are

- increaseValidatorCount(additional)
- setValidatorCount(new)
- scaleValidatorCount(factor)

Which sounds like acts on the `minimum_validator_count`. Am I correct? Does it require special privileges to call this function?

**Edit #2**: I tried calling these methods with `sudo`, to increase it to 3 but then I checked my `minimum_validator_count` and it was still the same `1`.

**Edit #3**: What is the entity `validator_count` and how is it different from `minimum_validator_count` in the staking genesis config?

Comment: Bump: so with a count of 1 I will make assumption you are running with --dev. With --chain local-polkadot then it would be 2. I too have tried those extrinsic to no avail. I would like to see an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The staking pallet has two storage items to configure this:

1. [`ValidatorCount`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cfb5bc6f1a92207785a0bdd321039096685623c8/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L224). This is the desired number of validators that staking tries to elect via its [`ElectionProvider`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cfb5bc6f1a92207785a0bdd321039096685623c8/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L109). All of the transactions you named alter this value.
2. [`MinimumValidatorCount`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cfb5bc6f1a92207785a0bdd321039096685623c8/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L229), as its documents clearly dictate, is the minimum acceptable number of validators that staking can work with. If the number of validators falls below this, then new eras are not triggered, meaning that the chain remains with the old validator set. See [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/323eecd2de38b9631d9c162997261e43c886828c/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L451).