# No new era planned after changing validator count

Tags: staking

I have submitted a proposal for setting the validator count to 3 which was earlier 5 through custom spec. My proposal got approved . The validator count decreased to 3. So now 2 nodes should be removed automatically but this was not the scenario. Instead the era time increased but the blocks are getting finalised. So if anyone knows why the era time increased kindly let me know.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `MinimumValidatorCount` storage.

Check if your new validator count is smaller than that.

Documentation & knowledge:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cfe926282a284f7bdbf7b336eb78e80f51858577/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L281-L284
- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cfe926282a284f7bdbf7b336eb78e80f51858577/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L493-L498
- [What happens if validator count < minimum_validator_count?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1844/what-happens-if-validator-count-minimum-validator-count?rq=1)